# send-mailmessage not working in a script

Tags: powershell-2.0

Im having a strange problem with the cmdlet send-mailmessage. When using direclty on powershell it works perfectly but when i want to use it on a script to edit the different variables to mail users the mail doesnt send properly.
I have this piece of code:

```
$userInfo = $fornamn+" "+$efternamn+" "+$usernm+" "+$pass  
$from = "administrator@"+$ADinfo.dnsroot  
$to = $fornamn+"."+$efternamn+"@cuebid.se"  
$smtpserver = "cb-dc02.cuebid.local"  
$subject = "sys-konto"  
Send-MailMessage $to $subject $userInfo $smtpserver -from $from
```

$fornamn,$efternamn and $pass are variables created earlier in the script and all are type String.

When using the script i dont receive any mail but in the exchange logs i can see that a mail is received
When directly in powershell i create the variables and the run send-mailmessage it works flawless
any ideas why?

Comment: w/o info what is $ADInfo and how do you define/ retrieve it it will be hard to tell anything. Also - try to run script with -noexit parameter and make sure there are no errors, and if there are - what are they.

Comment: there are no errors when running the script.
I get $ADinfo.dnsroot by running $ADInfo = Get-ADDomain, but the variable $from is a string so the line $from = "administrator@"+$ADinfo.dnsroot is a string which retrieve the domain and create the mailaddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this behaviour here.  Also, you can combine your string variables more elegantly, because in double quotes variable substitution occurs (mind the backtick in front of the dot):

```
$userInfo = "$fornamn $efternamn $usernm $pass"
$from = "administrator@"+$ADinfo.dnsroot
$to = "$fornamn`.$efternamn@cuebid.se"
$smtpserver = "cb-dc02.cuebid.local"
$subject = "sys-konto"
Send-MailMessage $to $subject $userInfo $smtpserver -from $from
```

Are you sure the mail did not end up being marked as spam?  I know it doesn't seem logical, because when executed from the command line, you say it works.  Still, worth double checking.

The only other thing I can think of, is that in your .ps1 file, the variables don't contain the exact same values (maybe a space too much somewhere).

Comment: well sir you were right, it was in the junk mail. My bad for not looking there first
thanks for the input

Comment: Doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but glad you found it. Can you mark this as answered, so other people don't spend time on this?